# Do we have such system?

Tags: discussion, voting

So, I'm getting downvoted by a currently unknown force.

I don't remember when it started, but there were some "serial voting reversed" notifications at my [achievements] tab. Recently my questions and answers (both very old and new) are getting downvoted, one for each. I'm not saying it has a huge impact, this system's weakness is its strength, everyone can climb up easily, falling down requires a serious effort :P

However, I'm getting derailed again, so do we have a system, or a bot (like @Community),  that cleans up/hides my stuff by downvotes?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is such a system:

There's more detail on [meta stack exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/149375), but here's the gist:

> Every night around 03:00 UTC, a voting fraud detection script is run that looks for patterns such as these. It basically looks for users who have voted on another user's posts many times. The threshold number is fairly low within a given amount of time (the exact mechanics are kept secret). When the system detects this pattern, all of the votes cast from that user to the user affected are reversed, and a "voting corrected" event is added to the affected user's reputation history to indicate what has occurred.

I see two such corrections in your profile from a few weeks back, it looks like this is probably such a reversal. The system doesn't tell me any more information, but if this happens again we can investigate.

Comment: But what about patience?